# Is it possible to use @Valid in Service layer? What could be the workaround?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

I am writing a validation service where I need not validate the incoming request object directly, but validate it after some manipulation.

```
 @Service
 public class FooCreationService {
                private String validateFoo(@Valid Foo foo) {    
                    return "";
                }
            }



  public class Foo {
        @Size(min=1, max=60)
        @NotBlank(message="Product description required.")
        private String fooDescription;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When Spring Boot finds an argument annotated with @Valid, it automatically bootstraps the default JSR 380 implementation — Hibernate Validator — and validates the argument.
When the target argument fails to pass the validation, Spring Boot throws a MethodArgumentNotValidException exception.